# NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest NSData not accessible out side block

Tags: iphone, nsurlconnection

here i'm trying to fetch html from mywebpage, bt somethng is wrong..here's my code..i have declared html string in my controller.h file.

```
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responde,NSData *Data,NSError *error){

            html=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
            //NSLog(@"%@",html);  //WORKING

        }];

  NSLog(@"%@",html); //NOT WORKING
```

Answer (score 1):

use `__block NSString *html` outside the block.

**Edit:**

```
  __block NSString *html;   //please notice __block is with two underscores.

  [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:urlRequest queue:queue completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *responde,NSData *Data,NSError *error){

        html=[[NSString alloc] initWithData:Data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
        //NSLog(@"%@",html);  

    }];

NSLog(@"%@",html);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it should be accessed only inside the completion block, because callback will get "html" data only after receiving data from web service. You cannot access it outside the block.

Comment: then what should i do to access my html variable which has stored data came from webserivce?

Comment: Access it inside the block and if you want, you can send the data to other methods.